# Nested custom functions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to build nested custom functions to get an output of a cross table. Many crosstab functions allow to make calculations only within the table while I need to divide each value in the table by a value from a different logic. But because I need a lot of cross tables I want to build a function that will combine cross table and division of each value by an external data.

Here is the initial data:

```
Key <- c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
Speed <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Slow", "Slow", "Mid", "Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid")
ID <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10))
init_dt <- data.frame(ID, Key, Speed)
```

And the first function for cross table with simple frequesncies:

```
crosstab <- function(dt, col_y, col_x){
  col_y = sym(col_y)
  col_x = sym(col_x)
  dt %>% group_by(!!col_y, !!col_x) %>% 
    tally() %>%
    spread(!!col_x, n)
}
```

When I apply this function to the initial data I get the following:

```
crosstab_key <- crosstab(init_dt, "Key", 'Speed')
crosstab_key

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   Key [3]
  Key     Fast   Mid  Slow
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 Blue       2     2     1
2 Red        1     2     1
3 Yellow     2     2     2
```

After that I calculate the value for the division using the same initial data but separate function:

```
div <- function(dt, id, col_y, col_x) {
      col_y = sym(col_y)
      id = sym(id)
      col_x = sym(col_x)
      dt%>% select(id, col_y, col_x) %>%
        group_by(!!col_x) %>% 
        distinct(!!id) %>%
        summarise(count = n()) 
    }
```

When apply this function I get the following:

```
div_speed <- div(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed")
div_speed

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Speed count
  <chr> <int>
1 Fast      5
2 Mid       6
3 Slow      4
```

I want to divide each value in the cross table `crosstab_key` by values in `div_speed`. I can combine the functions this way:

```
crosstab(init_dt, "Key", 'Speed') %>% rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(across(everything())/div(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed")$count)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise:  Key
  Key     Fast   Mid  Slow
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Blue     0.4 0.333  0.25
2 Red      0.2 0.333  0.25
3 Yellow   0.4 0.333  0.5
```

But I want to avoid making separate `div` function.  So my question is how to combine these two functions together (as you can see the arguments are the same: `dt, id, col_y, col_x` because they are coming from the same initial data frame) so that I will not need to create `div_` object every time I need to divide cross tables by some values. On top of that I also need to round each value to four decimals `mutate_at(2:4, funs(round(., 4)))`.

Comment: I think it would help to see some example of how you apply the functions to your data and what you expect as output.

Comment: crosstab function is very easy: it's just three arguments: data frame, and two columns in it. I then run dplyr functions to get frequencies (see first table).

Comment: `df<- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(everything())/div$B) %>%mutate_at(2:4, funs(round(., 4)))` this wont work bc you are dividing at lease one character column by a number and this throws an error so we can't go to any next steps with your code. As noted above share the expected out in a table format so we can see what you desired result is.

Comment: I think now it should be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Tidyverse

You can simplify your two functions into one.

```r
library(dplyr) # you need version >= 1.1 !!
library(tidyr)

Key <- c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
Speed <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Slow", "Slow", "Mid", "Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid")
ID <- factor(c(seq(1:15)))
init_dt <- data.frame(ID, Key, Speed)

# set the order you want in advance!
init_dt$Key   <- factor(init_dt$Key, c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow"), ordered = TRUE)
init_dt$Speed <- factor(init_dt$Speed, c("Fast", "Mid", "Slow"), ordered = TRUE)


crosstab <- function(dt, id, col_y, col_x){
  
  dt |> 
    mutate(count = n_distinct(!!sym(id)), .by = all_of(col_x)) |> 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = all_of(col_y),
                names_from = all_of(col_x),
                names_sort = TRUE,
                values_from = count,
                values_fn = ~ sum(1/.)) |> 
    arrange(!!sym(col_y))
  
}

crosstab(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Key     Fast   Mid  Slow
#>   <ord>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Blue     0.4 0.333  0.25
#> 2 Red      0.2 0.333  0.25
#> 3 Yellow   0.4 0.333  0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Following your steps, I calculated at first the distinct number of `id`s per each `col_x`. Which is done here:

```
    mutate(count = n_distinct(!!sym(id)), .by = all_of(col_x)) |>
```

Then, you want to calculate the number of `id` per `col_x` and `col_y` and divide it by the number we calculated before.

We could do it in two steps:

```
    summarise(subcount = sum(1 / count), .by = all_of(c(col_y, col_x))) |> 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = all_of(col_y), 
                names_from = all_of(col_x), 
                values_from = subcount)
```

But the `values_fn` argument in `pivot_wider` allows us to make operations on the spread column. Therefore we can do it in one go.

### With table

It seems you can get the same result with `table` and `prop.table`:

```r
Key <- c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
Speed <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Slow", "Slow", "Mid", "Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid")
ID <- factor(c(seq(1:15)))
init_dt <- data.frame(ID, Key, Speed)

# to keep the right order
init_dt$Key   <- factor(init_dt$Key, c("Yellow", "Red", "Blue"), ordered = TRUE)
init_dt$Speed <- factor(init_dt$Speed, c("Slow", "Mid", "Fast"), ordered = TRUE)


crosstab <- function(dt, id, col_y, col_x){
  
  table(dt[[col_y]], dt[[col_x]]) |> 
    prop.table(margin = 2) |> 
    as.data.frame.matrix() |> 
    tibble::rownames_to_column(col_y)
  
}

crosstab(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed")
#>      Key Slow       Mid Fast
#> 1 Yellow 0.50 0.3333333  0.4
#> 2    Red 0.25 0.3333333  0.2
#> 3   Blue 0.25 0.3333333  0.4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Force 4 digits into `kable`

```r
crosstab(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed") |> 
  knitr::kable(format = "pipe", digits = 4, format.args = list(nsmall = 4))

| Key    |   Slow |    Mid |   Fast |
|:-------|-------:|-------:|-------:|
| Yellow | 0.5000 | 0.3333 | 0.4000 |
| Red    | 0.2500 | 0.3333 | 0.2000 |
| Blue   | 0.2500 | 0.3333 | 0.4000 |
```

Comment: Almost. I need it in the original order and rounded to at least 4 decimals.

Comment: For the original order you should cast the variable as factors in advanced. In that way you can be sure that any operation will respect the order you want

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Can I ask you to add rounding as well?

Comment: That is not issue. You need to set it when you write it in a csv or in a table like kable

Comment: I made some edits to help you out with the order and the 4 digits. I've also added another solution using table

Comment: Unfortunately, non of the options work to preserve the original order. In fact, I specifically need to avoid to do anything extra once the cross table is made. Do you think there is a way to integrate factor order into the function?

Comment: You can try to add those lines into the function, but there is guarantee that the order is what you want. How can the machine know that slow is less than fast?

Comment: The function I wrote will set the rows and the columns in order, but you need to find a way to communicate the machine the order you want and that really depends on your specific case. Can you define a rule for it?

Comment: I just added `names_sort = TRUE` and it fixed it. I did not use it before. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to understand how your function works and use it outside the custom function. However, when I try to enter the names of the column it says the column specified in `all_of()` does not exist. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: use debugonce(crosstab) to understand what happens directly inside the custom function.  If it says it doesnt exist, it may be coz you didnt assign a value to col_x or col_y or id. Maybe a mispell?

Comment: Edo, maybe you could help me with this follow up questions as well? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75828351/weighted-crosstables-with-custom-functions-and-dplyr

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to combine them to make a function for cross tabs. I noticed you are using `spread()` but `pivot_wider()` is the superseding function that should be used if you have access to it.

```
crosstab <- function(dt, col_y, col_x){
  col_y = sym(col_y)
  col_x = sym(col_x)
  
  dt %>% 
    count(!!col_y, !!col_x) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    group_by(!!col_x) %>% 
    mutate(pct = round(n/sum(n),4)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-n) %>% 
    pivot_wider( names_from = !!col_x,  values_from =  pct)
}

crosstab_key <- crosstab(init_dt, 'Key', 'Speed')
```

Comment: Thank you. However, you suggest to divide each n by sum(n) but that is exactly what many functions in cross tab propose. I need to divide each n by values in `div_speed` which I calculated with function `div`.

Comment: our codes both produce the same output table your have at the end of your post. is there a case where the sum(n) is not the same as the value in div_speed if so can you show that example as well?

Comment: Right. I changed the ID column in the data. I need to count only sum of IDs. That is why I use `distinct()` in my `div` function.