# Weighted crosstables with custom functions and dplyr

Tags: r

I have this data and want to build a custom function that can calculate weighted frequencies and then to divide them by weighted number of unique IDs in Speed:

```
    Key <- c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
    Speed <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Slow", "Slow", "Mid", "Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid")
    ID <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10))
Weight <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2)
    init_dt <- data.frame(ID, Key, Speed, Weight)
```

And a function that can create a cross table and divide each value by number of unique IDs in each Speed group.

```
crosstab <- function(dt, id, col_y, col_x){
  dt %>%  
    mutate(count = n_distinct(!!sym(id)), .by = all_of(col_x)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = all_of(col_y), 
                names_from = all_of(col_x),
                names_sort = TRUE,
                values_from = count,
                values_fn = ~ sum(1/.)) 
}
```

And here is how the output looks like:

```
crosstab(init_dt, "ID", "Key", "Speed")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Key     Fast   Mid  Slow
#>   <ord>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Blue     0.4 0.333  0.25
#> 2 Red      0.2 0.333  0.25
#> 3 Yellow   0.4 0.333  0.5
```

However, I have weight column to each ID now and instead of dividing by a sum of unique ID, I want to divide each value in the cross table by sum of weights of those unique ids. But also, the frequencies in the cross table have to be also weighted when I use pivot_wider().

Here is how the function could possibly look like, but it does not work

```
crosstab_w <- function(dt, id, wght, col_y, col_x){
      dt %>%  
        mutate(summarize(sum(wght)) .by=distinct(!!sym(id)), .by = all_of(col_x)) %>% 
        pivot_wider(id_cols = all_of(col_y)*wght, 
                    names_from = all_of(col_x)*wght,
                    names_sort = TRUE,
                    values_from = count,
                    values_fn = ~ sum(1/.)) 
    }
```

I can do this in three steps. I first calculated weighted frequencies:

```
> test <- init_dt %>% select(Key, Speed, Weight) %>%
+   count(Key, Speed, wt = Weight) %>%
+   pivot_wider(id_cols = Key,
+               names_from = Speed,
+               names_sort = TRUE,
+               values_from = n)
> test
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Key     Fast   Mid  Slow
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Blue     1     0.4   0.5
2 Red      0.2   0.9   0.5
3 Yellow   1.1   0.6   1.2
```

Next, I calculated weighted `n` of unique IDs in Speed by group:

```
> den_test <- init_dt %>% group_by(Speed, Weight) %>%
+   distinct(ID) %>%
+   group_by(Speed) %>%
+   summarise(count = sum(Weight))
> den_test
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Speed count
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Fast    2.3
2 Mid     1.6
3 Slow    1.7
```

And lastly, I divided each column in `test` by count in `den_dest`. I did it by hand because I cannot find an option how to divide each column of a tibble by a corresponding value in another tibble. But the result will be like this and that is what I need:

```
     Key       Fast    Mid      Slow
1   Blue 0.43478261 0.2500 0.2941176
2    Red 0.08695652 0.5625 0.2941176
3 Yellow 0.47826087 0.3750 0.7058824
```

I want to combine all of these steps in one custom function like `crosstab` but with weights now.

Comment: I dont understand why you need to sum the weight by distinct ids. You have 15 unique ids in your example, so it makes no difference to consider unique ids or not. Also there is no expected final output in your example.

Comment: Edo, I added more information and expected output.

Comment: your final expected output doesn't sum to 1 neither by row or column. Are you sure that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing! I need only unique IDs counted (+ they have to be weighted).

Comment: I don't understand the last division you did, coz I tried `test[2:4] |> apply(1, function(x) x / den_test$count)` but I dont get your same number.

Comment: I do this: `test$Fast/2.3`, then `test$Mid/1.6`, and finally `test$Slow/1.7`

Comment: oh, I see the problem now: I don't get your numbers from den_test! I get: 2.8 1.8 2.3

Comment: In fact, I dont get your same numbers from test either. And I am running the code you wrote here with the data you wrote here. Have you changed something..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is not entirely clear to me, therefore I'm just gonna suggest you how to make that last passage you need.

Try with this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# calculate den_test exactly as you did
den_test <- init_dt |> 
  distinct(Speed, ID, Weight) |> 
  summarise(count = sum(Weight), .by = Speed)

# join den_test to make that division before pivoting
test <- init_dt |> 
  count(Key, Speed, wt = Weight) |> 

  # join here by Speed
  left_join(den_test, by = "Speed") |> 

  # and divide
  mutate(n = n / count) |> 

  # pivot after to get you result
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Key,
              names_from = Speed,
              names_sort = TRUE,
              values_from = n)
test
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Key      Fast   Mid  Slow
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Blue   0.5    0.389 0.261
#> 2 Red    0.0714 0.333 0.217
#> 3 Yellow 0.429  0.278 0.522
```

Your function could be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

weighted_crosstab <- function(dt, id, wght, col_y, col_x){
  
  den_test <- dt |> 
    distinct(!!!syms(c(id, wght, col_x))) |> 
    summarise(count = sum(!!sym(wght)), .by = all_of(col_x))
  
  test <- dt |> 
    count(!!!syms(c(col_y, col_x)), wt = !!sym(wght)) |> 
    left_join(den_test, by = col_x) |> 
    mutate(n = n / count) |> 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = all_of(col_y), 
                names_from = all_of(col_x),
                names_sort = TRUE,
                values_from = n)
  test
}

weighted_crosstab(init_dt, "ID", "Weight", "Key", "Speed")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Key      Fast   Mid  Slow
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Blue   0.5    0.389 0.261
#> 2 Red    0.0714 0.333 0.217
#> 3 Yellow 0.429  0.278 0.522
```

Where `init_dt` is:

```
Key <- c("Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Blue")
Speed <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Slow", "Slow", "Mid", "Slow", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid", "Fast", "Mid")
ID <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10))
Weight <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2)
init_dt <- data.frame(ID, Key, Speed, Weight)
```

Comment: Thank you, Edo. I was thinking about multiple stages in a function too. However, you count `den_test` not exactly how I do in my code. it is important that we sum weights of unique IDs in each group of Speed. That is why I group like this: `den_test <- init_dt %>% group_by(Speed, Weight)` then get distinct IDs `distinct(ID)` and then group by Speed again `group_by(Speed)` and get sum of Weights  `summarise(count = sum(Weight))`

Comment: I'm quite sure that the distinct of the three columns and group by 2 and distinct of one, gets exactly the same result.

Comment: I see. Yes, it does. However, it changes the order of values in `den_test`  which then affects the division.

Comment: Edo, I will accept your solution if you can fix the last point. No worries if you don’t have time for it.

Comment: hey @Laura sorry about that. I didnt understand you point. why would the order affect the division?

Comment: no problem. you will see the difference when you keep the original order like in the question. It is important to divide in that order to know the proportions for each group.